# Possible to access default styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Somewhere I read that ExpressionBlend can create copies of the default style of a wpf control for the developer to edit.
However, VisualStudio can not. (At least I haven't found a way...)

Is it possible to access/view the default styles (and templates) of wpf controls.

A Gui would be nice, but a (web)-resource to view the styles would also do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [Style snooper](http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/05/Revamped-Style-Snooper.aspx) or [ShowMeTheTemplate](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#ShowMeTheTemplate) to get the default styles for WPF controls.

You can also do it in code if you'd prefer. Check out the "Where Does The Theme Style Come From" in this [article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate).

The code:

```
Style ts = typeof(Button).GetProperty("ThemeStyle",
   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(myButton,
   null) as Style;
```

[DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT]